# What is Captain Kidd's treasure?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I have found 14/24 trinkets for Peg Leg. After returning each back to Peg Leg a naval map location is revealed to me. Now the latest one has me aboard the Octavius, and I died a few times trying to escape it after I found another fragment of a map.

I would like to know just what it is to be found by seeking the treasure of Captain Kidd? What is Captain Kidd's treasure?

Comment: Shard of Eden at the end of the treasure hunt that allows Connor to deflect shots fired on him!

Comment: I don't really have the time. Feel free to pinch it though (genuinely)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will receive a "Shard of Eden" that is a permanent passive bonus that gives you a chance to deflect bullets that are fired at you.

Based on personal experience, it seems to deflect around about 1/3 of the bullets that would normally hit you.

Interestingly enough, it even works when you're controlling Desmond (through unexplained video game magic).

It's a nice bonus, but not something that's game changing unless you're being killed by guns a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the @danRhul comment:

> Shard of Eden at the end of the treasure hunt that allows Connor to deflect shots fired on him!

I havent done it myself so I can't say if it's true.

EDIT: Now I've done it, and yes it is true. You get an item that makes you dodge bullets.

Comment: I haven't done it yet either but I've heard this is the case.

Comment: It's not a pain. But the maps in the general stores. Find those collectibles, then do the 5 missions related. Did the missions part in under an hour.

Answer (score 0):

You also get Captain Kidd's "robes", which turn your mohawk assassin into a Johnny Depp-like pirate captain.